# How to handle events of different DOM elements of a ember view?

Tags: ember.js

My ember view is a container for other DOM elements. I am interested in handling events of some of those contained DOM elements independently. For example, in a view of backbone.js, we can handle them as

```
events: {
   'click #some_button': 'handle_button_click',
   'click #some_anchor': 'handle_anchor_click'
}
```

How to do similar thing in view of emberjs?. Do I have to create independent view for each DOM element that I am interested in handling events for?

Comment: Have you already read about the action helper of Ember?

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a view for every element.

Just use the `{{action}}` helper, you can catch these events in the controller or the router.

More on that here: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/

Answer (score 0):

In EmberJS, you dont need to bind events to functions. Ember provides default bindings to DOM events. I would suggest you to go through [EmberJS guide on events](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/) to understand the bindings.

Also you want to bind functions on elements, you can do this following way. I am taking your BBJS example for the code which may help you understand better.

```
var App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
    click : function(e) {
       if($(e.target).attr('id')==='some_button') {
         this.handle_button_click(e);
       } else if($(e.target).attr('id')==='some_anchor'){
         this.handle_anchor_click(e);
       }
    },
    handle_button_click : function(e) {//someCode};
    handle_anchor_click : function(e) {//someCode};
});
```

You can actually have code of `handle_button_click` or `handle_anchor_click` in same `click` function inside the conditions, unless you feel to make it more modular...